# VueGapi do nothing when requesting with multiple scopes

Tags: vue.js, google-api-js-client

here's my Vue3 `main.js`

```
app.use(VueGapi, {
    apiKey: 'MyApiKey',
    clientId: 'myClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    discoveryDocs: ['https://classroom.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile",
  })
app.mount('#app')
```

but I need to provide many scopes, so I did

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly'];
```

and assign `SCOPES` to `scope`

```
app.use(VueGapi, {
        apiKey: 'MyApiKey',
        clientId: 'myClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        discoveryDocs: ['https://classroom.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
        scope: SCOPES,
      })
    app.mount('#app')
```

From my vue component, calling

```
this.$gapi.login().then(({ currentUser, gapi, hasGrantedScopes }) => {
          console.log({ currentUser, gapi, hasGrantedScopes })
        })
```

when I press the login button only works when I set `scope` to singular scope like `scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile"`, but nothing happens (no error, no nothing) when I assigned `SCOPES` to `scope`. Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scope` should be a space-delimited string.](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#client-setup)

Try

```js
...
    scope: SCOPES.join(' ')
...
```

Comment: Oh wow that settles it... thanks!